# Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'ng-class' since it isn't a known native property in Angular 2

Tags: parsing, angular, ng-class

I am trying to apply CSS style conditionally on an img attribute based on the value of a boolean 'isLoginPage' in Angular 2.0.0-beta.15. The portion of html is as below:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#/">
    <img src="/src/resources/images/logo.png" [ng-class]="{logoStyle:  isLoginPage, navLogoStyle: !isLoginPage}" /></a>
```

logoStyle and navLogoStyle are mentioned in css class and its added in the main html page. In the corresponding component, I am setting value of isLoginPage as shown below:

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgClass} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
selector: 'header',
inputs: ['isLoginPage'],
templateUrl: './header.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink, NgClass]
})
 export class HeaderComponent {
   isLoginPage: boolean;
   constructor(){
    if(condition){
     this.isLoginPage = true;
   }
  }
```

But when I am trying to see the result, styles are not applied and the error 'Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-class' since it isn't a known native property' is shown. Can somebody guide me.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Angular2, the parser now looks for the [camelCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx) name of the directive. So in your case you want to change `ng-class` to `ngClass`

```
<img src="/src/resources/images/logo.png" [ngClass]="{logoStyle:  isLoginPage, navLogoStyle: !isLoginPage}" /></a>
```

[You can see the documentation for the implementation here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html)

Comment: it's actually `camelCase`. so `[ngClass]` instead

Comment: Thank you very much @Sean Larkin . I was using ng-class and it should be ngClass. :)

Comment: Ooops thats right, I was thinkging about the class reference thats right it is camel case. Updated the information.